# Loss of file permissions

Tags: windows-explorer

I cannot use my photos. I am being told that I do not have permission to enter a folder, or open a file.

I can fix it photo by photo, but

1. I took these photos with my camera
2. I put them onto this laptop
3. It would not be logical to have to fix each and every photo.

Comment: How do you fix it photo by photo. Can you try taking ownership https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc753659.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the folder and go to

> properties->security->advanced

Now,

1. change the owner to your user account.
2. click on enable inheritance and check the below box.
3. Double click your user account in table and grant full control to user .

Apply the settings and you would be able to access the files